# intellij plugin using TreeClassChooserFactory not show recommended class?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm writing a intellij plugin to let people choose a class, I find the code the move method in intellij open source code.

The move method picture is like this which will show all project class.
[image]

but when I using the following code the pic is this
[image]

There is no recommend class, after I type some text, still nothing.

```
TreeClassChooser chooser = TreeClassChooserFactory.getInstance(myProject).createWithInnerClassesScopeChooser(
                        "choose serviceClass", GlobalSearchScope.projectScope(myProject), new ClassFilter() {
                            public boolean isAccepted(PsiClass aClass) {
                                return aClass.getParent() instanceof PsiFile && !aClass.isInterface();
                            }
                        }, srcClass);
                chooser.selectDirectory(pojoClass.getContainingFile().getContainingDirectory());
                chooser.showDialog();
```

Comment: Strange, works for me in IDEA 2017.2 EAP. I'd suggest to put breakpoint (e.g. TreeJavaClassChooserDialog#getClassesByName, ContributorsBasedGotoByModel#processNames) and see what happens there.

Comment: seem find the reason, after i replace my plugin from intentionAction to normal action, it worked. when it's using the intentionAction, the TreeJavaClassChooserDialog#getClassesByName is never called after show the dialog, it was called after cancel the dialog, seem strange.
thanks alot for your help.

Comment: That seems to be a bug in the IDE, fixed in the upcoming 2017.2 release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems to be a bug in the IDE, fixed in the upcoming 2017.2 release.